# jQuery mobile change radio button css properties

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-selectors, radio-button, radio-group

Does anyone know how to change the css properties of a jQuery mobile radio button group?  I am trying to highlight a radio group with the color red using the following code but have been unsuccessful.  Any ideas would be appreciated!

[Here is my full project on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/austin350s10/o2apxu73/4/)

```
//radio button array
var radio_groups = {};

//find each radio button in the section of the form i want the code to look at
$('#myID' + myCodeGeneratedNumber).find(":radio").each(function(){   
        //fill array
        radio_groups[this.name] = true;
});

//loop through each radio button
for(group in radio_groups){

      //check to see if a button is checked or not
      if (!!$(":radio[name="+group+"]:checked").length) {
          //not working - should add a green highlight
          $(":radio[name="+group+"]").css('box-shadow', '0px 0px 0px #FF7575');
      }
      else{
          isValid = false
          //not working - should add a red highlight
          $(":radio[name="+group+"]").css('box-shadow', '0px 0px 4px #A7E9A7');
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Austin, based on your fiddle, here is a solution.

I modified the `if` condition (you had two `!`).

For the color, I navigated to the icon (inside the label, not the input) to change its color.

```
$(function () {
    $("input[name=jquery-submit]").on("click", function () {
        $.post('test.php', $("form[name=form1]").serialize(), function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }).error(function () {
            alert("Error submiting the form");
        });
        //return false;
    });

    $('a[id^="btnPage"]').click(function () {
        var groupNum = +($(this).attr('id').replace('btnPage', '')) - 1; //get the group number to validate
        var isValid = true; //added local variable to track validation
        $('#group' + groupNum + ' input[type=text]').each(function () {
            if (this.value === '') {
                isValid = false; //form was not valid
                $(this).css('background-color', '#FF7575');
                shake(this);
            } else {
                $(this).css('background-color', '#A7E9A7');
            }
        });

        var radio_groups = {};
        $('#group' + groupNum).find(":radio").each(function () {
            radio_groups[this.name] = true;
        });

        for (var group in radio_groups) {
            if (!$(":radio[name=" + group + "]:checked").length) {
                isValid = false;
                $("input:radio[name=" + group + "]").each(function() {
                    $(this).next().find('.ui-icon').css('background-color', '#FF7575');
                    shake($(this).next());
                });
            } else {
                $("input:radio[name=" + group + "]").each(function() {
                    $(this).next().find('.ui-icon').css('background-color', '');
                });
            }
        }

        if (!isValid) { //when form is not valid, return false
            return false;
        }
    });
});

function shake(div) {
    var interval = 100;
    var distance = 10;
    var times = 4;
    $(div).css('position', 'relative');
    for (var iter = 0; iter < (times + 1); iter++) {
        $(div).animate({
            left: ((iter % 2 == 0 ? distance : distance * -1))
        }, interval);
    }
    $(div).animate({
        left: 0
    }, interval);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/o2apxu73/13/

EDIT: added `shake` call when no radio selected

Comment: And small edit as my initial solution was not good when checking => selecting val => checking => changing value

Comment: Thank you so much...works like a charm!  Any idea how to apply the shake function i have to the radio button label as well?

Comment: See my edited answer and fiddle (just need a `shake($(this).next());`)

Answer (score 0):

For a radio button the visible DOM element is actually the `<label>`, not the `<input>`.  Therefore you need to target the `<label>` when setting the CSS. One way is to get the parent wrapper with class `ui-radio` and then find the `<label>` within it:

```
$(':radio[name="gender"]').parent(".ui-radio").find("label").css('box-shadow', '0px 0px 3px #FF7575');
```

You can also use the **[siblings()](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)** function:

```
$(':radio[name="gender"]').siblings("label").css('box-shadow', '0px 0px 3px #FF7575');
```

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/o2apxu73/9/)**